# How can I get the commnunity followers by using laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to create the community follow system by using Laravel eloquent relationship, I am unable to solve the problem, please help

Basically I am trying to create the event system which will based on the communities (e.g: Business & Professional, Health & Wellness, Science & Technology, etc).

**Its giving me the following error**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;acp_db.community_users&#039; doesn&#039;t exist (SQL: select * from `community_users` where `community_users`.`id` = 8 limit 1) in file /Users/muhammadowais/mowais/academics-provider/website/working/acpapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
```

**To get the followers of the community by Id** I created the following tables

1) Users

2) event_categories (you can say communities)

3) community_user `(user_id, community_id)`

**Controller**

```
public function communityBySlug($slug){
        $eventCategory = EventCategories::where(['slug' => $slug])->first();
        $eventCategoryId = $eventCategory->id;


        // Getting users by community id
        $users = CommunityUsers::find(8)->users();

        return Response::json(
            [
                'data' => $eventCategory,
                'community_followers' => $users
            ]
        );
    }
```

**Model: CommunityUsers**

```
class CommunityUsers extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['community_id', 'user_id'];
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that community users is the model that maps your many to many relation table, you should specify the correct table name in the database for that model.

```php
class CommunityUsers extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'community_users';
}
```

Also, keep in mind that Eloquent doesn't support **composite primary keys**, so you have to set either `community_id` or `user_id` as *primary key* in the `CommunityUsers` model to use the `find()` method on it, otherwise Laravel would search by the `id` column.

I'd rather insert a new primary auto increment column to the relation table, and retrive a spceific community with a where filtering like this:

```php
CommunityUsers::where('community_id', $id)->first();
```

**Note:** You could also make that filter as a `CommunityUsers` scope method.

Furthermore, notice that you relation from `Users` to `CommunityUsers` is a **one to many** relation (one `User` maps to many `CommunityUsers` pair ([community_id, user_id]))

#### Rethinking the relation mapping

If you consider the three tables, that can be modeled as a **many to many** relation among `Users` and `Communities`.

The relations should be:

**Model: User**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function communities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EventCategories::class, 'community_user', 'user_id', 'community_id');
    }
}
```

**Model: EventCategories** (Assuming that is your Community model)

```php
class EventCategories extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'community_user', 'community_id');
    }
}
```

**Note:** The code above might need some tweaking based on your models and their table definitions.

After that relation definition you can use it directly on the `EventCategories` model:

```php
public function communityBySlug($slug){
    $eventCategory = EventCategories::with('users')
        ->whereSlug($slug)
        ->first();

    return Response::json(
        [
            'data' => $eventCategory,
            'community_followers' => $eventCategory->users
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `community_id` is the primary key in your `CommunityUsers` table, the problem is in your `Users()` function:

```
public function Users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users');
}
```

the second parameter of `belongsToMany` should be the foreign key, which is `user_id`

Comment: I did this ```return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users', 'user_id');``` Its giving me this error ```SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'acp_db.community_users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `community_users` where `community_users`.`id` = 8 limit 1)```